# group values in array with range of {n} (length prop) to next item

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, range, grouping

I'm not good at writing complex group functions. So that I hope anyone can help me here. I've been looking for a solution but nothing found what can resolve my problem.

What I want is to pass a list of array to "group a function" (see below) that group the items by max range of "length property" (see object in array) to the next array item.

I hope I could explain what I wanted to achieve.

```
// input
let list = [
    {start: 5, length: 1},
    {start: 8, length: 1},
    {start: 9, length: 1},
    {start: 10, length: 1},
    {start: 11, length: 1},
    {start: 12, length: 1},
    {start: 20, length: 1},
    {start: 24, length: 1},
    {start: 25, length: 1},
    {start: 37, length: 2},
    {start: 39, length: 1},
    {start: 40, length: 1},
];

// group function like
groupedList = groupBy(list, (prevItem, nextItem) => {
    return (nextItem.start - prevItem.start) === prevItem.length;
});

// output
let groupedList = [
  [
    {start: 5, length:1},
  ],
  [
    {start: 8, length:1},
    {start: 9, length:1},
    {start: 10, length:1},
    {start: 11, length:1},
    {start: 12, length:1},
  ],
  [
    {start: 20, length:1},
  ],
  [
    {start: 24, length:1},
    {start: 25, length:1},
  ],
  [
    {start: 37, length:2},
    {start: 39, length:1},
    {start: 40, length:1},
  ],
];
```

Comment: why is `37` and `39` in one group?

Comment: because 37 have a length prop-value of 2 ! so the next item should be 39

Comment: Could you please include what you have already tried? Also please elaborate more on what you want to achieve. It is still unclear to me.

Comment: you can see what i want to achieve. Input + Output (code example) !

Comment: And its not really easy to explain it in words what i want to achieve, so that i tried to explain it in code form :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the predecessor and group it in the actual `start` is equal of the sum of the predecessor `start` and `length`.

```js
var list = [{ start: 5, length: 1 }, { start: 8, length: 1 }, { start: 9, length: 1 }, { start: 10, length: 1 }, { start: 11, length: 1 }, { start: 12, length: 1 }, { start: 20, length: 1 }, { start: 24, length: 1 }, { start: 25, length: 1 }, { start: 37, length: 2 }, { start: 39, length: 1 }, { start: 40, length: 1 }],
    result = list.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (!i || aa[i - 1].start + aa[i - 1].length !== a.start) {
            r.push([a]);
        } else {
            r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);



console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if I've understood your question. My idea is creating a object and push all results to this object. Something like this:

```
var groups = Object.create(null);

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];

    if(!groups[item.start]) groups[item.start] = [];

    groups[item.results].push({
        Start: item.start,
        Length: item.length
    });
}

var result = [];

for (var x in groups) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[x] = groups[x];
    result.push(obj);
}
```